# Hide Table when all results from select change function are hidden in tbody

Tags: jquery

I have a selection menu that filters results using jQuery. I would like to hide the entire table when the results are empty (all tbody content is hidden). So basically, thead needs to get hidden. Here's what I have so far:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
function calculate() {  

$('tbody tr').show();
var sel_day = $('select[name="day"] option:selected').text();
var sel_time = $('select[name="time"] option:selected').text();
var sel_language = $('select[name="language"] option:selected').text();

if(sel_day == 'Day' && sel_language == 'Language' && sel_time == 'Time') {
    return; }   

$('tbody tr').each(function() {
    var col_day = $(this).find('td').first();
    var col_language = $(this).find('td').eq(1);
    var col_time = $(this).find('td').eq(2);

    if(col_day.text() !== sel_day && sel_day !== 'Day') {
        $(this).hide();}           

  if(col_language.text() !== sel_language && sel_language !== 'Language') {
           $(this).hide();}        

     if(col_time.text() !== sel_time && sel_time !== 'Time') {
        if($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $(this).hide();}

                 }  }); }      

$('select[name="day"]').change(function() {
calculate();  });

$('select[name="language"]').change(function() {
calculate(); });

$('select[name="time"]').change(function() {
calculate();  }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="day" class="form-control selectpicker">
<option value="">Day</option>
<option value="">Tuesday</option>
<option value="">Wednesday</option>
<option value="">Thursday</option>
<option value="">Friday</option>
<option value="">Saturday</option>
<option value="">Sunday</option>
</select>

<select name="language" class="form-control selectpicker">
<option value="">Language</option>
<option value="">English</option>
<option value="">French</option>
</select>

<select name="time" class="form-control selectpicker">
<option value="">Time</option>
<option value="">11:00</option>
<option value="">1:00</option>
<option value="">5:00</option>
   <option value="">5:30</option>

</select>    
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">

<thead>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#efefef" width="30%"><strong>Day</strong></th>
<th bgcolor="#efefef" width="40%"><strong>Language</strong></th>
<th bgcolor="#efefef" width="30%"><strong>Time</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>Monday</td>
 <td>English</td>
 <td>1:00</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>Tuesday</td>
<td>English</td>
<td>11:00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Saturday</td>
<td>French</td>
<td>5:00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another function to check if any rows are visible. If no then hide the whole table. This function will use the `:visible` selector to get only rows which are visible, 0 means all are hidden.. As simple as that.

And dont forget to `.show()` the table at each `calculate` function call.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function calculate() {
    $('table').show();
    $('tbody tr').show();
    var sel_day = $('select[name="day"] option:selected').text();
    var sel_time = $('select[name="time"] option:selected').text();
    var sel_language = $('select[name="language"] option:selected').text();

    if (sel_day == 'Day' && sel_language == 'Language' && sel_time == 'Time') {
      return;
    }

    $('tbody tr').each(function() {
      var col_day = $(this).find('td').first();
      var col_language = $(this).find('td').eq(1);
      var col_time = $(this).find('td').eq(2);

      if (col_day.text() !== sel_day && sel_day !== 'Day') {
        $(this).hide();
      }

      if (col_language.text() !== sel_language && sel_language !== 'Language') {
        $(this).hide();
      }

      if (col_time.text() !== sel_time && sel_time !== 'Time') {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
          $(this).hide();
        }

      }
    });
  }

  $('select[name="day"]').change(function() {
    calculate();
    checkIfEmpty();
  });

  $('select[name="language"]').change(function() {
    calculate();
    checkIfEmpty();
  });

  $('select[name="time"]').change(function() {
    calculate();
    checkIfEmpty();
  });
});

function checkIfEmpty() {
  if ($('tbody tr:visible').length == 0) {
    $('table').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="day" class="form-control selectpicker">
  <option value="">Day</option>
  <option value="">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="">Thursday</option>
  <option value="">Friday</option>
  <option value="">Saturday</option>
  <option value="">Sunday</option>
</select>

<select name="language" class="form-control selectpicker">
  <option value="">Language</option>
  <option value="">English</option>
  <option value="">French</option>
</select>

<select name="time" class="form-control selectpicker">
  <option value="">Time</option>
  <option value="">11:00</option>
  <option value="">1:00</option>
  <option value="">5:00</option>
  <option value="">5:30</option>

</select>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#efefef" width="30%"><strong>Day</strong>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#efefef" width="40%"><strong>Language</strong>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#efefef" width="30%"><strong>Time</strong>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>1:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>11:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Saturday</td>
      <td>French</td>
      <td>5:00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### EDIT

To check for all tables:

```
function checkIfEmpty() { 
    $('table').each(function() { 
        if ($(this).find('tbody tr:visible').length == 0) { 
            $(this).hide() 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This worked great but I didn't think about what would happen if there were multiple tables. Can your function be modified to work when you have a situation where for example you have 3 tables, 2 have empty tbody's and 1 has a value? Obviously since this script checks for all tbody's, it will detect at least 1 and the other 2 tables will not get hidden.

Comment: Well am sure you can modify it to suit your needs if you get the concept.!! Happy coding!!!

Comment: This last bit of functionality is still a little lost on me. I tried this to get the function to check each table but it doesn't work. Any additional help would be appreciated: `code` function checkIfEmpty()  {
  $('table').each(function() {
  if ($('tbody tr:visible').length == 0) {
   $('table').hide()
      }   });
   }} `code`

Comment: I edited the answer, you have to use `$(this)` to access the specific table being iterated